# Role based access control for JSF 1.2?

Tags: java, jsf, spring-security, rbac

I need suggestions on implementing role based access control in an existing JSF 1.2 application.

Here are a few constraints I have:

1. Stuck with JSF 1.2, cannot upgrade to a higher version
2. No custom solution, though writing something for integrating to an existing API or framework (Spring Security? any other?) shall be fine.

Comment: Do you have an authentication system already? If so, which? Container managed authentication or homegrown?

Comment: 100% homegrown authentication mechanism. Not too very complicated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your best bet is to homegrow the role based access control on top of that. Else you have to switch the authentication as well.

Comment: If there's a recommended framework proven to work well with JSF 1.2, we might actually consider switching over the authentication mechanism. Anything from top of your mind?

Comment: Just use container managed authentication (also known as `j_security_check`). This supports role based authentication. In JSF you can get the user principal and thus also check the roles by `ExternalContext#getUserPrincipal()`. Alternatively, you can also go for Spring Security, I can only not tell from top of head how to integrate this in JSF.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. I'll consider your suggestions.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin  It's a standalone authorization library.